# jQuery ui shake effect moves other elements as a side effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to shake an "#error_message" div. I'm doing:

```
$('#error_message').effect('shake', {times: 2, distance: 5}, 200);
```

The div gets shaken, the problem is that the div below moves vertically, kind of moves 10 pixels down while the animation is in progress, then it returns back to its position. There is no other JS event attached and "#error_message" is a div (so it's a block).

Sorry I cannot show html and JS at the moment. Any hints why this could be happening?

Comment: well the div bellow moves becouse the error_message needs the space to move around doesn't it ? you could try to play with the error_message div position css and z-index so that it sits on another layer than it's current siblings

Comment: error_message only moves horizontally, so my understanding is that there should be no other divs moving vertically

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok this is happening because your errors div needs room to "shake", so what you need to do, is take this div *out* of the flow of the rest of your content that follows it.

If your errors div has a fixed height you can do something like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="error_message>Error content</div>
  <div id="content">rest of your content, other divs etc</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#error_message {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}

#content {
  margin-top; 100px;
  position: relative;
}
```

It's really hard to debug something like this because you didn't provide the code. Perhaps you can create a small sample of your markup and CSS on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I updated my answer, with an approximate solution, but basically you should post your code.

Comment: Thanks, I understood the problem and fixed it following your pattern. Sorry, next time I will post a example :)